# Flutter: AppBar, Back Button, Status Bar color

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I don't know how this happened, but somehow the colors of my app changed and I didn't even change anything by myself. So at first everything was black (status bar, AppBar title, Back button, etc.) and now it's all white.
I already changed **iconTheme** and **primaryColor** in the *main.dart* but it doesn't work.
Can you please help me out?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Defining the Theme of the application in main.dart. You could customize to any choice of Colour combinations, themes, fonts, and font sizes.

Theme() and ThemeData() would help you out in that I feel.

In the following code below i've just set a constant font theme throughout the app. But theres more you can do and find out yourself.

```
 theme: ThemeData(
            textTheme: GoogleFonts.latoTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme)),
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not the problem I guess. If I switch the colors the changes will only apply for like a millisecond and then everything turns white again.

Comment: Oh I got it now, thanks! Inside the main.dart I needed to put this in -> appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark,